# acts_as_follower issue with following users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-follower

I have a User model created in devise:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  after_create :build_profile

  acts_as_follower

end
```

Which has an associated `profile` with the `user`. And I'm using the [acts_as_follower gem](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower) to give this model the ability to follow another model.

I want the `User` to follow a `Profile`, so i have my profile model set up like this:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/f7/61/b3/f761b3ae57801975e0a605e805626279.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

  acts_as_followable

end
```

The Profile model should be followable according to the gem, which is how I have it set up.

I ran the migrations as required `rails generate acts_as_follower`

In my `profile_controller` iv set up the following methods:

```
  def follow
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    current_user.follow(@profile)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def unfollow
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id]) 
    current_user.stop_following(@profile)
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

And in my `route.rb` file i have the following:

```
  resources :profiles do
    member do
      get :follow
      get :unfollow
    end
  end
```

Now in my profiles show view iv set up the button as so:

```
  <% if !@profile.followed_by?(current_user) %>
    <%= link_to "Follow", follow_profile_path(@profile), class: "btn btn-success btn-outline btn-sm"%>
  <% end %>
```

According to my knowledge and documentation this should work, but for some reason it does not follow the user or create the association between the `user` and the `profile` to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, in my gemfile I installed from the master branch, so change your gemfile to this:

```
gem "acts_as_follower", github: "tcocca/acts_as_follower"
```